# Mean stack can't post to mongodb doesn't seem to do anything, get 0 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code. What I want to do is to be able to post via the inputted data then when clicking the button it should post (create) and save in mongoDB. Here's my code so far. Any help is appreciated!

Html (Note: Category.name works):

```
<section class="wrapper" *ngIf="category">

  <h2>Create a new post</h2>
  <p>within the category <span class="category">{{ category.name }}</span> </p>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus [(ngModel)]="title">
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="{{ category._id }}">
    <textarea name="content" placeholder="Post content" required [(ngModel)]="content" ></textarea>
    <button (click)="createPost()">Publicera</button>
  </form>
  </section>
```

Component ts file :

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  category: Category;
  title: String = '';
  content: String = '';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private appService: AppService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let _id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');

    this.appService.getCategory(_id)
    .subscribe(data =>this.category=data);
  }

  createPost(){
    let post = new Post();
    post.title = this.title;
    post.content = this.content;
    this.appService.createPost(post);
  }

}
```

Service file:

```
  createPost(post: Post){
      let payload = {
        "title": post.title,
        "content": post.content
      }
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/post/", payload, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(response => {});
  }
```

Server file (server.js)

```
app.post('/api/post', (req, res) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var newPostData = { userId: req.body.userId, category: req.body.category, postId: req.body.postId, commentId: req.body.commentId, title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content, publishedDate: today, editedDate: null };
    var post = new Post(newPostData, function(err) {
    });
    post.save();
});
```

Comment: can you add a full error message and are you getting data in `req.body`?

Comment: I don't get any errors, I can't seem to get anything within req.body, I can however change category: "testtext" and it will work

Comment: just print `req.body` in console see are you getting data or not.

Comment: "undefined" doesn't seem to read it

Comment: can you add your server.js code also?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a callback in save function, check the document [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents).

```
var newPostData = { userId: req.body.userId, category: req.body.category, postId: req.body.postId, commentId: req.body.commentId, title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content, publishedDate: today, editedDate: null };
var post = new Post(newPostData);
post .save(function (err) {
    if (err) {console.log(err) return res.send(err)};
        // saved!
});
```

Comment: Hm this does not seem to work. I tried adding this but doesn't seem to do anything either

Comment: app.post('/api/post', (req, res) => {
    var today = new Date();
    // Hämtar de data som skickats med POST
    var newPostData = { userId: req.body.userId, category: req.body.category, postId: req.body.postId, commentId: req.body.commentId, title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content, publishedDate: today, editedDate: null };
    var post = new Post(newPostData);
    post.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {console.log(err); return res.send(err)};
        // saved!
    });
});

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// Hämtar scheman
var Category = require('./models/category');
var Post = require('./models/post');
var User = require('./models/user');